# In Java, what happens when we return from a function with Future threads in progress?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, concurrent.futures

I wanted to know what happens when we don't wait for Future Tasks to get completed and return before it?
Does the future tasks still completes, or all the threads are killed once I return from function.
For ex:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class IdGenerator() {
    private DBPersister dbPersister;
    public String generateId(){
        String id = UUID.randomString();
        Future<Void> persistIdInDB =  dBPersister.persist(id);
        return id;
    }    
}
```

I want to return id to downstream as soon as it gets generated and don't want to wait for storing it in Data base. Does returning from a function kills all future task created in the function? Or I can be assured that the function dbPersister.persist once called will be executed fully? If not, is there any way I can achieve the same in Java?

Comment: it does not kill the task, you can with relative high certainty assume that it will persist the data. Of course exceptions during storage will be list this way if you simply "forget" the future.

Comment: It depends on the context. I faced a similar case few weeks ago in a JPA / Play 2 context, while executing functionnal test. The caller of generateId can close the transaction before the dBPersister finish its job. Technically, it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can be sure about when returning from your method is that:

- `dBPersister.persist(id);` will be invoked
- The current thread will not block, as you're not invoking `get` on your `Future<Void>`

What will concretely happen in terms of persistence can only be discovered by looking at the implementation of `dBPersister.persist(id);`, as well as whether persistence was successful due to environmental variables (e.g. database down, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I am not concerned about what happens in persistence, wether it fails or passes. You can assume it as a generic code which connects to DB and writes it. I just wanted to make sure that the persist function is called and not blocked.

Comment: @harshitmodani then the answer's yes. Returning a `Future` on its own does not imply blocking, or terminating the invocation if `get` etc. is not invoked on the `Future`. It is just a mechanism to de-couple the method's execution from whatever comes back from its termination.

Answer (score 1):

`Future` is only an interface. It's up to individual implementations how they provide the methods `cancel()`, `get()`, `isCancelled()` and `done()`.

You could, for example, write a method which returns a `Future` which just does the job synchronously:

```
    public Future<Void> print(String x) {
        System.out.println(message);
        return new Future<Void>() {
            @Override
            public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCancelled() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isDone() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Void get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Void get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
                    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

Equally you could write your own implementation that doesn't do the work until `get()` is called! (This isn't good code in a multi-threaded context, but it's illustrates the point):

```
 public Future<Void> foo(String x) {
        return new Future<Void>() {

            private boolean done = false;

            @Override
            public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCancelled() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isDone() {
                return done;
            }

            @Override
            public Void get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
                System.out.println(message);
                done = true;
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Void get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
                    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
                return get();
            }
        };
    }
```

`DBPersister` is either a from a third-party library, or something of your own. We can't guess how it has implemented `Future`.

A mainstream of example of something that returns `Future`s is `ExecutorService`. A typical `ExecutorService` will keep running until something calls its `shutdown()`, whereupon it will stop accepting new tasks, process what's on its queue, then terminate. The JVM won't stop until the last thread has finished.

However, `Runtime.exit()` has the potential to abruptly kill everything. Avoid calling it; or if you can't avoid it, learn about shutdown hooks.